# There is a way that I could run $ roscore and don't record log datas?

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a way that I could run $ roscore and don't record log datas?

Or, record a specific size of data and delete de older ones?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187456/there-is-a-way-that-i-could-run-$-roscore-and-don%27t-record-log-datas?/) by [JoaoPedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/12316/joaopedro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't turn off logging completely in ROS, but you can adjust the logger levels with the appropriate log4cxx and python logging configuration files as described in [rosconsole configuration](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Configuration) and [rospy logging configuration](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging#Advanced:_Override_Logging_Configuration)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-25**:
There are also many generic log rotation tools which could be applied to the output to limit size.